# calling .net function (IVI.net) with correct type

Tags: overloading, calling-convention, python.net

I am trying to acquire data from an R&S Oscilloscope RTB 2004 using the IVI.net driver.
Connection to the oscilloscope is established.
I can create an object named "oszi" in the repl or jupyter-lab (python 3.9, pythonnet 3.0.1) and do various settings queries with the instrument.
But I'm failing to query waveform data from the device.
There is a C# example code, which works fine. Code looks like this:

```
string[] chanArr = { "CH1", "CH2", "CH3", "CH4" };
int chan = Channel.SelectedIndex;
PrecisionTimeSpan maximumTime = PrecisionTimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(Timeout.Text));
IWaveform<double> waveform = null;

    try
    {
        if (!driver.Channel[chanArr[chan]].Enabled)
            driver.Channel[chanArr[chan]].Enabled = true;
...
            waveform = driver.WaveformAcquisition.Waveform[chanArr[chan]].ReadWaveform(maximumTime, waveform);
```

Locals in the debugger, before ReadWaveform is called.
[image: locals-section Visual-Studio]

waveform is a null with the type Ivi.Driver.IWaveform.

So I tried to do the same in python with the following code:

```
import pathlib, clr
PlRTB2004dll = pathlib.Path("C:/Program Files/IVI Foundation/IVI/"
    "Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/RohdeSchwarz.RsRtx 2.4.0/RohdeSchwarz.RsRtx.Fx40.dll")
clr.AddReference(str(PlRTB2004dll))
import RohdeSchwarz.RsRtx as RsRtx
import System
import Ivi.Driver as Ividriver
visaResStr = "USB::0x0AAD::0x01D6::205720::INSTR" 
oszi = RsRtx.RsRtx(visaResStr, True, True)
# now the oszi-ocject is "alive"
oszi.Display.SendMessage = "Connection to Python established"
# displays on the instrument's screen
dummywafD = Ividriver.IWaveform[System.Double]
timeOutTimeSpan = Ividriver.PrecisionTimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.)
print(dummywafD)
print(timeOutTimeSpan)
# fixed readout-object on channel 1 for testing
wac = oszi.WaveformAcquisition.Waveform["CH1"]
# now comes the error:
ret = wac.ReadWaveform(timeOutTimeSpan, dummywafD)
del(oszi)
```

which gives the following error:

```
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.33.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/XXX/software/labjack/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/XXX/software/labjack')
<class 'Ivi.Driver.IWaveform[Double]'>
00.00:00:10.000000000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\labjack\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\XXX\software\labjack\untitled0.py", line 31, in <module>
    ret = wac.ReadWaveform(timeOutTimeSpan, dummywafD)

ArgumentException: Das Objekt mit dem Typ "System.RuntimeType" kann nicht in den Typ "Ivi.Driver.IWaveform`1[System.Byte]" konvertiert werden.
   bei System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   bei System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei Python.Runtime.MethodBinder.Invoke(BorrowedReference inst, BorrowedReference args, BorrowedReference kw, MethodBase info, MethodBase[] methodinfo)
```

Sorry, for the German output. The first line means "cannot by converted to".